# IAST transliteration of ड़ and ढ़ of Devanagari

Tags: devanagari, hindi, iast

What are the IAST symbols for

- **ड़** as in लड़का, पहाड़, जड़ etc
- **ढ़** as in पढ़ाई, बाढ़, पीढ़ी etc

I have glanced through the Wikipedia page for IAST but couldn't find desired content.

<del>However IPA pronunciations of **ड़** and **ढ़** seem to be denoted as **ṛa** and **ṛha** respectively.</del>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary reason is that IAST was designed for the classical Indic languages which don't have those consonants. The diacritic *nukta* was introduced in more modern times. The conventional neo-IAST transliterations are ड़ = ṛ(a) and ढ़ = ṛh(a), which is *not* IPA – IPA would be [ɽə] and [ɽʰə].

Comment: I know ड़ and ढ़ are very close to *Ra* र sound. But **ṛ** is used for vowel ऋ  (However I feel there are low chances of ambiguity)

Comment: The under-dot is multi-purpose in IAST. The potential ambiguity does not arise in the classical languages.

Comment: Just FYI, this tool called [AksharaMukha](http://aksharamukha.appspot.com/roman) seems to be using **r̤** for ड़ in IAST. Not sure if it was made-up by the author or if it's a latest modification to the IAST standard.